# Forward port and keep source IP

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, nat

I have a system with a static IP address running several LXC containers.
I can communicate with the containers over an interface as it would be a physical machine.
One of this containers is a postfix server. I forward port 25 from the host to the container, however in the progress the source IP get's replaced with the interface one, resulting in postfix failing rDNS checks.

**Setup**
Host access to internet via interface `eth0`, IP `188.xxx.xxx.xxx`
Container IP address `192.168.1.12` (`br2`) on the hosts site and `192.168.1.2`(`eth0`) on the container side.
Container gain internet access via host as default gateway and iptable rule.

There are other containers with similar setups, containers don't talk directly to each other but by iptable rules for specified ports.

I post all iptable rules in case they interfere with each other

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [760:48985]
:INPUT ACCEPT [707:45761]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [114:7445]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [50:2740]

# Route HTTP & HTTPS to web container
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:80
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:443

# Route internal mysql request to mysql container
-A PREROUTING -i br1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:3306
-A PREROUTING -i br2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:3306

# Route mail from outside to mail container
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:25
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:143
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:587
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:993
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4190 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:4190

# Route mail from web container to mail container
-A PREROUTING -i br1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:25
-A PREROUTING -i br1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:143
-A PREROUTING -i br1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:587
-A PREROUTING -i br1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:993
-A PREROUTING -i br1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4190 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:4190

# Mark packages
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o br1 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o br2 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o br3 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT
# Completed
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [35371:3912708]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [48:2620]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [29159:6870938]

# All containers are allowed to place calls from inside to outside
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o br1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o br2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o br3 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
# Completed
```

IP Route in case it matters

```
192.168.1.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 br1
192.168.1.2     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 br2
192.168.1.3     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 br3
```

**How should I modify this rules to keep the source IP or should I approach this differently?**

Comment: To clarify: I want traffic to be seen as it comes from the host to the _outside_, but need the original client ip _inside_.

Comment: To be clear : once the outgoing trafic NATed with the public IP, you still want to be able to get the original private IP ? In this case you should approach things differently...but from now i don't know how because i am not sure to really get what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: No: A calls my server B. B forwards traffic to C and currently replaces A's IP with the IP from B. Now C tries to validate the IP via rDNS and (of course) finds nothing because it's private address space, so the check fails and the mail get's rejected.  
What I want is A calling B, B forwarding to C **keeping the IP from A**, C can validate correctly, send response via B, which replaces C's private IP with the public one from B, so A never knows there is C. (As supposed by NAT)

Comment: What about not masquerading outgoing packets to br2 on port 25 ?

Comment: "_What I want is A calling B, B forwarding to C keeping the IP from A,_" That is called routing. If you NAT when you route, you normally translate the destination address, not the source address. Why are you translating the source address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop these rules:

```
-A POSTROUTING -o br1 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o br2 -j MASQUERADE
```

They perform SNAT on all traffic going to `br1` and `br2`.  Normally you will only want to have one MASQUERADE rule on the interface connected to the Internet.

If each container is on on a separate bridge, I would put the containers in different subnets.  They don't need to be full /24s.  A /30 would is sufficient to route one IP address.

Comment: I mark this a the correct answer to my question, but to anyone who might stumble upon this while searching note that this will break the forwarding between container interfaces

Comment: @Kimmax. Updated with routing that won't break and won't need NAT for local connections.

Comment: thanks, however they actually are /32's already (IP scheme is as is because they were on the same subnet initially) and the bridges don't have a uplink at all

Comment: @Kimmax Convert them to /30s. These can be subnets of /192.168.1.0/24 if you wish.  /32s cause the kind of issues you are encounteriing.

Comment: Using `/30` wastes half the addresses. You should be able to use `/31` for point-to-point networks. Way back in the year 2000, [RFC 3021, Using 31-Bit Prefixes on IPv4 Point-to-Point Links](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3021) was approved.

Comment: @RonMaupin If that is a concern on 192.168 addresses. Try a 172.16 or 10.  Minimal wastage of private addresses shouldn't be a concern if you are on 192.168.1.0/24  Just move them to 192.168.10.0

Comment: We don't actually set all user networks to `/24`. Actually, we have run out of all RFC 1918 address space...

Comment: @RonMaupin  All three blocks?  Have you considered IPv6 (at least for inter-container communication) ?   Or add routes for the container IPs via the containing host's IP.

Comment: @BillThor, yes, all three blocks (our network is larger than many ISPs' networks), and we are rolling out IPv6, too, but IPv6 is a challenge because of vendors' promises of IPv6 support that ends up being smoke and mirrors, and we are trying to do it right the first time. It turns out that the average number of times a company changes its IPv6 address scheme and must readdress everything is three times, but we only want to do it once because the network is just too large.